# in app purchase - consumable product

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, in-app-purchase

I am implementing in app purchase in my application.  as per the requirement **product should be purchased** every time I pressed "BUY" button in my application.

For that on itunesconnect web site in which kind of category my product will fall? **Consumable or non-consumable.**

I am confused on selecting the category.
I have read some documents for this but still its confusing.

Comment: Consumable is for something like game currency, which can be used up. Non-consumable is for something like extra game features, which is only bought once and will be available forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's docs say

> Consumable products must be purchased each time the user needs that item.

And you say:

> Product should be purchased every time I pressed "BUY" button in my application

Don't you feel like it's the same sentences?

So, yes, you should choose **consumable**.

Answer (score 0):

That means your product is **consumable**. Check [this link](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) for all the details you need.